# Onclick function is Not Working on my AMP Site

Tags: amp-html

**HTML code:**

```
<span class="button-text" style="font-size: 12pt;">
    <a onclick="AboNewsletterFunction()" id="clickButton">
        <span class="label" style="font-size: 10pt;"> Abonnieren sie unseren Newsletter </span>
    </a>
</span>
```

and than in the `<script>` tag I have my function. So on AMP site, that doesent work.

The function self, start is referencing to a html-link or start an intent

Answer (score 1):

Inline Scripts are also not allowed in amp you can check for 'Actions and Events' of amp.

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/learn/amp-actions-and-events/?format=websites.

OR else you can use amp-scripts where you can add add addEventListener for a click event.